# select2-rails gem: installed assets and called function but dropdown not changing (TypeError: undefined is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are several posts similar to this on SO but I have yet to find one that has an answer checked correct. I am trying to implement the select2-rails gem in my Rails 3.2 app following the instructions at the [GitHub page](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails). I bundled the gem and included the javascript and css files. I then added a js function call like the one in the [sample code](http://select-2-example.herokuapp.com/). My select bar, however, isn't changing at all.

Javascript include:

```
# application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require select2
//= require jquery-1.11.0.min.js
//= require lightbox.min.js
//= require parsley
//= require ./jquery.datetimepicker.js
//= require Stripe/jquery.payment.js
//= require_tree .
```

CSS includes:

```
# application.css.less
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 *= stub active_admin
*/
```

My page with the form, just trying to replicate the example:

```
# new.html.haml

=content_for :title, 'Post a job'
= javascript_include_tag "https://js.balancedpayments.com/1.1/balanced.js"
:javascript
  var _balanced_marketplace = "#{@balanced_marketplace}";
  var _categories = #{raw(@categories.to_json)};
  $(document).ready(function() { $("#e1").select2(); });
...
...
%select{id: "e1"}
  %option{value: "AL"} Alabama
  %option{value: "WY"} Wyoming
```

The end of my script and the HTML generated by the HAML:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("#e1").select2(); });
</script>
      <select id='e1'>
        <option value='AL'>Alabama</option>
        <option value='WY'>Wyoming</option>
      </select>
```

All of this just results in a normal select drop-down with no select2 styling/features.

In the Javascript console I am seeing the following error for my function call:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I am not extremely familiar with Javascript but I'm guessing this means that there is a problem with the function `select2()'. However, I am not sure how to begin debugging this since I've followed the gem installation instructions word-for-word. When I view the page source I see the select2 js library being loaded as follows:

```
<script src="/assets/select2.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error probably has something to do with you loading jQuery twice:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require select2
//= require jquery-1.11.0.min.js
```

What you're doing is loading jquery, then loading select2.  Then you load the second jQuery which wipes out the first jQuery (that had the select2 associated with it).  So when you call:

```
$("#e1").select2();
```

select2 no longer exists on the second jQuery.

I can't imagine that you really need two jQueries loaded, so get rid of one.